# Force eager image loading on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

On my website, I have several images with an onload and onerror callback

```
<img onload="imgCallback()" onerror="imgCallback()" class="article-img" src=":assets:/price/12-2.jpg" alt="A chart showing vitamin and mineral content of liver, kidney, spleen, heart, broccoli, kale, banana and apple" />
```

Some initialization is only done after all images have loaded because I need the full height of the container element after all images are shown.

This works fine on my desktop, however, it seems to not work on some mobile browsers. I have tested this on my Android Chrome browser and it seems to only load images lazily after I scroll far enough down, delaying page initialization that is expected to happen on the initial loading of the website.

I can't really think of any other way of solving this as I need the full width of the container post image loading, something I don't know statically, therefore I am asking if there is a way to signal to the browser that it should eagerly load images?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/).
I simply had to add `loading="eager"` to my image tags.